# Find volume from rotating region bounded by $y=e^x$, $y=\cos(πx^2/2)$ and $x=1$ about $y$-axis

Tags: integration, volume

Find the volume of the solid generated by rotating the region bounded by the curves 
$$y=e^x,\>\>\>\>\>y=\cos(πx^2/2),\>\>\>\>\>x=1$$

about the $y$-axis.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please update your question with what you have tried and where are you getting stuck, so we may guide you further.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the shell method to integrate over $x$ as follows,

$$\int\limits_0^1 2\pi x\left(e^x-\cos\frac{\pi x^2}2\right)dx = 2(\pi-1)$$